# reconstruct inputs from outputs in regression neural networks in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

Say we train a multilayer NN in tensorflow for a regression task (i.e. multi input and multi output case). Then we have new instances and we apply the trained model and of course we get the corresponding outputs. Is there a way to backpropagate the outputs and reconstruct the inputs in tensorflow in an easy/efficient manner? What I am thinking is to then use the difference of the original and the reconstructed inputs of the new instances as a QC measure i.e. if the reconstructed inputs are not close enough to the originals then we have a problem etc. I hope I am making myself clear.

Comment: No, because in general there are many different inputs that may produce a given output.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you cannot take a trained model and try to get the corresponding input. The reason for this is that you have infinite possible solutions for each output.

Furthermore, backpropagation is not passing an output backwards through the network. Its the idea of determining what parameters in the model are contributing to what extent to loss function. This will not give the inputs to these hidden layers, but the extent at which the weights affected your decision.

Comment: Sure but then what is the best way to QC the performance for the new instances?

Comment: What is QC? If you are curious about how a deep learning network is trained you should ask it in the Data Science Stack Exchange. We can't write equations in Tex here unfortunately so explaining it would be difficult.

Comment: @user9810829, here is a link to that community: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: QC = Quality Control.

Comment: My query is not about training. As mentioned above assume I have trained a network and have done typical accuracy measures and launched it. After the launch, I'd like to give the user some sort of confidence, i.e. QC or accuracy measure, on the predictions from the new instances.

Comment: @user9810829, ok so what is the problem? Take some of your new data and use it as a new testing set then report the resulting performance metrics. Your question makes very little sense due to poor grammar or a misunderstanding of basic deep learning concepts to be honest. Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: For the new data one would not know the answer (e.g. target valus) so it is not possible to use the usual performance metrics.

Comment: @user9810829, you would not give performance metrics with unlabeled data for a model trained and validated using a labeled set. You can always collect another labeled set of data and use it to benchmark your model anew.